# Laplace approximation from a log-posterior in R

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, posterior, laplace-approximation

I would like to perform a Laplace approximation of a log-posterior.

The evolution of a cancer cell at given time $t_j$, $j = 1,\cdots,n$ for an experiment $i$ follows the following Poisson distribution,
$$
y_i(t_j) \sim \text{Pois}(\mu = \alpha_0 \exp(-\alpha_1 e^{-\alpha_2 t_j})), 
$$
with $\alpha_k > 0$ for $k = 0,1,2$

Let denote $y_i(t_j) \equiv y_{i,j}$.
I computed the Likelihood $L(\vec{\alpha}|y_i)$ for a given experiment $i$,

$$
L(\vec{\alpha}|y_i) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} p(y_{i,j}) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \left( \mu^{y_{i,j}} \cdot e^{-\mu} \right)
$$

Let $\theta_k = \log(\alpha_k)$ and considering large variance priors, I chose arbitrarily a Gamma distribution as prior for the $theta_k$ with parameters $a = 1/2$ and $b = 0.001$ in order for the variance of this distribution to be large.

This gives me the following log-posterior,
$$
p(\vec{\theta}|y_i) \propto \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_{i, j} \cdot \ln(\mu^{y_{i,j}} \cdot e^{-\mu}) + \ln(f(\theta_0, a, b)) + \ln(f(\theta_1, a, b)) + \ln(f(\theta_2, a, b))
$$

where $f(\theta_k, a, b)$ is the PDF of the gamma distribution for the parameter $\theta_k$, $k = 0,1,2$.

This results in the following R code:

```r
log.mu <- function(alpha, t_j) {
  log(alpha[1]) - alpha[2] * exp(- alpha[3] * t_j)
}

log.likelihood <- function(theta, t, experiment) {
  n <- length(experiment)
  alpha <- exp(theta)
  
  result <- sum(sapply(1:n, function(j) {
    dpois(x = t[j], lambda = exp(log.mu(alpha, t[j])), log = TRUE)
  }))
  
  return(result)
}

log.prior <- function(theta) {
  alpha.prior <- 0.5
  beta.prior <- 0.001
  dgamma(theta, shape = alpha.prior, rate = beta.prior, log = TRUE)
}

log.posterior <- function(theta, t, experiment) {
  log.likelihood(theta, t, experiment) + log.prior(theta[1]) + 
  log.prior(theta[2]) + log.prior(theta[3])
}
```

Then I tried to perform a Laplace approximation of the log-posterior distribution $(\vec{\theta}|\text{experiment 1} \equiv D_1)$. That is the following R code:

```r
laplace.approximation <- function(log.posterior, inits, n_samples, 
                            ...) {
  fit <- optim(
    par = inits,
    fn = log.posterior,
    control = list(fnscale = -1),
    hessian = TRUE,
    ...
  )
  
  mean <- fit$par
  var_cov_matrix <- solve(-fit$hessian)
  samples <- rmvnorm(20000, mean, var_cov_matrix)
  
  return(list(
    mean = mean,
    var_cov_matrix = var_cov_matrix,
    samples = samples
  ))
}

inits <- c(theta0 = 0.001, theta1 = 0.001, theta2 = 0.001)
lapprox <- laplace.approximation(log.posterior, inits, 10000, 
              t = df$day, experiment = df$Exp1)

lapprox$mean
lapprox$var_cov_matrix
```

This gives me the following mean vector and variance-covariance matrix for $\theta_k$.

[image: laplace approximation results]

[image]

I'm wondering if that makes sense that the variance and covariance are so tiny. Or is there a problem in my algorithm or computation of the log posterior ?

Comment: try computing a finite difference hessian, e.g. using numDeriv, and see how that compares to the one optim is giving you. PS: that gamma prior youre using has received some criticism, e.g. http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/taumain.pdf

Comment: @JohnMadden better would be to use a large uniform distribution like Unif(0, 100) for example ?

Comment: check section 7.1 for Gelman's recomendations; something like U[0,100] is appropriate according to him when a "noninformative but proper prior distribution" is desired.